# Remove punctuation Perl

Tags: regex, perl, punctuation

Hye..how to remove punctuation?.. Actually I already try using `[:punct:]` but it does not work for all punctuation. It just only remove the dot `.` only...but other punctuations still have. My task is to remove paragraph, remove punctuation and change all text to lower case..

this is my text file which is snuker.txt

```
snuker berjaya menarik perhatian kbs.
19981230

Sam Chong"" kiri dan ooi Chin Kay memberi sumbangan besar kepada pembangunan snuker tanah air 
dengan merangkul pingat' emas sukan asia ti'ga belas tahun sembi'lan belas sembilan puluh lapan membuka 
lembaran baru snuker dan biliard tanah air apabila mereka kian disegani dan berjaya menukar tanggapan. 
negatif masyarakat tempatan terhadap sukan itu
```

and this is my perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;

if(! open(INPUT, '< snuker.txt'))
{
die "cannot opent input file: $!";
}


if(! open(OUTPUT, '> output.txt'))
{
    die "cannot open output file: $!";
}

select OUTPUT;

while($lines = <INPUT>)
{

    if($lines =~ s/[\s[:punct:]]+$/ /g)
    {
        print "$lines";
    }
}

close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;
close STDOUT;
```

the output are like this...the other punctuations still have..only `.` are gone..

```
snuker berjaya menarik perhatian kbs 19981230  Sam Chong"" kiri dan ooi Chin Kay memberi sumbangan besar kepada pembangunan snuker tanah air dengan merangkul pingat' emas sukan asia ti'ga belas tahun sembi'lan belas sembilan puluh lapan membuka lembaran baru snuker dan biliard tanah air apabila mereka kian disegani dan berjaya menukar tanggapan negatif masyarakat tempatan terhadap sukan itu
```

Comment: And the sample output please, quite better ;)

Comment: ok..i'll post the output

Comment: Punctuation in Perl is `\pP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;

if(! open(INPUT, '< test_file'))
{
    die "cannot opent input file: $!";
}

if(! open(OUTPUT, '> output.txt'))
{
    die "cannot open output file: $!";
}

select OUTPUT;

while($lines = <INPUT>)
{
    $lines =~ s/\n/ /g;
    $lines =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g;
    print lc("$lines");
}

close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;
close STDOUT;
```

Comment: yes...i already try this before..it manage to remove all punctuation..but it not remove the paragraph..i want remove paragraph, punctuation and change to lower case at the same time

Answer (score 6):

Remove the dollar sign from the regex. It makes your pattern match only at the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

$/ = ""; # read file per paragraphs

while (<>) {
    s/\p{Punct}//g;
    s/(?:\n|\s+)/ /g;
    print lc($_);
}
```

### Usage

```
perl script.pl < test_file >  output.txt
```

### Output

> snuker berjaya menarik perhatian kbs 19981230  sam chong kiri dan ooi chin kay memberi sumbangan besar kepada pembangunan snuker tanah air dengan merangkul pingat emas sukan asia tiga belas tahun sembilan belas sembilan puluh lapan membuka lembaran baru snuker dan biliard tanah air apabila mereka kian disegani dan berjaya menukar tanggapan negatif masyarakat tempatan terhadap sukan itu

Comment: Changed first regex by perl-ish `\p{Punct}`